# How can I have subprocess or Popen show the command line that it has just run?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

Currently, I have a command that looks something like the following:

```
my_command = Popen([activate_this_python_virtualenv_file, \
    "-m", "my_command", "-l", \
    directory_where_ini_file_for_my_command_is + "/" + my_ini_file_name], \
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False,
    universal_newlines=False, cwd=directory_where_my_module_is)
```

I have figured out how to access and process the output, deal with `subprocess.PIPE`, and make subprocess do a few other neat tricks.

However, it seems odd to me that [the standard Python documentation for `subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) doesn't mention a way to just get the actual command line as `subprocess.Popen` puts it together from arguments to the `Popen` constructor.

For example, perhaps `my_command.get_args()` or something like that?

Is it just that getting the command line run in `Popen` should be easy enough?

I can just put the arguments together on my own, without accessing the command `subprocess` runs with `Popen`, but if there's a better way, I'd like to know it.

Answer (score 2):

It was added in Python 3.3. According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.args):

> The following attributes are also available:
>
> `Popen.args` The args argument as it was passed to Popen – a sequence of
>   program arguments or else a single string.
>
> New in version 3.3.

So sample code would be:

```
my_args_list = []  # yourlist
p = subprocess.Popen(my_args_list)
assert p.args == my_args_list
```

Comment: // , And will that actually list out the full command that it runs? For example, could I just copy the result to a compatible bash terminal and have it work?